# turn a normal png image into json data and then store to object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

```
var imageUrl = {};

function convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, item, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        storemapImage(item, dataURL);
        console.log(imageUrl);
    };
}

function storemapImage(propertyName, url){
    imageUrl[propertyName] = {
    objectImage: url
    };
    return;
}


var src = "http://orig11.deviantart.net/c565/f/2013/092/1/6/mario_pixel_by_juli95-d607odz.png"

function capture (){
    convertToDataURLviaCanvas(src, "display1", "Image/png");
}
```

my intention is to turn a normal png image into json data and then store to a object (imageUrl) , here is my code , i tested alot but still didt get anything from it, can anyone take a look for me ?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/dpb8rcmn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to be happy with the answer here.

First of all, your "demo" link and the code here don't match.

In your code above, you are console logging imageUrl before you actually set it, so it won't be correct. if you move your console.log into the end of your storemapImage you should get a value.
In your demo, you are trying to console.log right after calling convertToDataURLviaCanvas but again it won't be set as onload takes at least a couple milliseconds to actually download the image.
You are also not actually setting img.src so it never attempts to load, and never fires the onload.

So fixing all that, it comes down to cross origin requests. Your browser has a security setting that prevents javascript from accessing things from other domains. Javascript can make an Image object and tell it to load, and you can save it to a canvas, but once you have done that, the canvas is considered tainted and you can not convert it to a url.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image has more info.

If the remote server has enabled CORS headers, then it can be done, but deviant art has not done so.

```
var imageUrl = {};

function convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, item, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        storemapImage(item, url);
    };
}

function storemapImage(propertyName, url){
    imageUrl[propertyName] = {
    objectImage: url
    };
    console.log('imageUrl', imageUrl)
    return;
}

function capture (){
    //convertToDataURLviaCanvas("https://orig11.deviantart.net/c565/f/2013/092/1/6/mario_pixel_by_juli95-d607odz.png", "display1", "Image/png");
  convertToDataURLviaCanvas("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/pie.png", "display1", "Image/png");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svr4r681/ is an updated fiddle with an image that does work, but still doesn't work with deviantart.